# weird behavior of Plot3D

Tags: plotting

I am just trying to plot a very simple function:

```
Plot3D[Abs[(2 Sqrt[n (1 + n)]Cos[4 Pi q])/((1 + 2 n) (-1 - 2 n - 2 n^2 + 2 n (1 + n) Cos[2 (4 Pi q)]))] - (2 n (1 + n) Sin[4 Pi q]^2)/(-1 - 2 n - 2 n^2 + 2 n (1 + n) Cos[2 (4 Pi q)]), {q, 0, 3}, {n, 0, 3}, PlotRange -> {0, 1}]
```

and I get a weird plot:(BTW, I cannot save this plot, it says "The specified setting for the option WindowSize cannot be used.")

[image]

Now I just change the range of q from 0~3 to 0~1:

```
Plot3D[Abs[(2 Sqrt[n (1 + n)]Cos[4 Pi q])/((1 + 2 n) (-1 - 2 n - 2 n^2 + 2 n (1 + n) Cos[2 (4 Pi q)]))] - (2 n (1 + n) Sin[4 Pi q]^2)/(-1 - 2 n - 2 n^2 + 2 n (1 + n) Cos[2 (4 Pi q)]), {q, 0, 1}, {n, 0, 3}, PlotRange -> {0, 1}]
```

Now I get a reasonable result:
[image]
Can anyone tell me what is going on here? Thanks!

Comment: What do you think is "weird" about it?  You can use `PlotPoints->100` to get better resolution, but until we know what "weird" means, we can't help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`PlotPoints -> 100` fixes everything.

Comment: That's what I need, thank you!